# Interest rate risk using copulas

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, risk, yield-curve, covariance

In order to simulate an interest rate yield curve, can I just estimate a covariance matrix of historical key rate data, simulate with a normal copula, spline my simulated key rates, then price my assets as a function of the simulated yield curves?

Alternatively, could I just spline historical key rate values and estimate risk as a function of those values?

Why is this insufficient? / Where does the need for stochastic models arise?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One reason is that your system needs to correctly price today's yield curve and interest rate options market , otherwise it is not arbitrage free versus existing instruments.   Historical data will not in general achieve that.

Comment: "need" is very strong. In some cases, yes your model should price the market correctly, but it's not a necessary condition for all possible uses. The approach described is very useful in risk management for example.

Comment: ok, since the OP referred to pricing of assets I assumed that consistency with the market would be important.